# CentOS - Firewall setup / Custom FTP & SSH ports

Tags: centos, firewall

I've got a centOS virtual box with GoDaddy.  By Default no firewall is enabled.

To the point: I want to set up the regular firewall set up. I however modified the SSH and FTP ports to custom ports rather the default.  When I ran system-config-securitylevel-tui I chose FTP, and etc... and saved it.  I then looked at the raw config file, and they showed the standard ports for ssh / ftp.  So I obviously went ahead and added those two ports to the custom list as: XXXX:tcp, XXXX:tcp, etc...

I don't want to enable it and restart and end up not being able to access the server (locking myself out).

Could someone verify ?

Thanks

Comment: Without posting any details (read: config files), how do you expect any of us to verify anything?

Comment: ErikA, I expect those with experience to be able to verify obviously; If you can't, don't comment.

Comment: @Michael - being belligerent is going to do you no favors here. When asking questions, it's expected that you give us enough information to give good answers. In your case that hasn't happened. If you want good answers, give good questions. Post your config (or a sanitized version if necessary) and we'll do our best to verify.

Comment: Additionally - does your VPS provider not give you some method of obtaining out-of-band access to your server? If not, I'd suggest changing providers.

Comment: As stated, "GoDaddy" is my provider. A LAMP dev would understand my question pretty clearly.

Comment: @Michael - sounds like either you don't know how to post your config or you aren't willing to do what it takes to get a good answer. As you can see from my user page, I've been around the block a few times - I know how things work here, and I know a good question from a bad question. Good luck getting a suitable answer. Does GoDaddy not give you out-of-band console access? That's the real solution to this problem. With that, you'd be able to make this change without being worried about getting locked out.

Comment: I do know, that's why I ask if someone could verify this basic procedure. -http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables

Comment: @Michael - I'm not sure how many times I'm going to need to repeat this - nothing short of posting your config is going to get you a for-sure answer on whether or not you risk locking yourself out. Posting a link to a generic how-to does *not* help us sanity-check *your* configuration. Honestly - I'm willing and trying to help you, but it appears as if you don't really want to be helped.

Comment: Can you give us the login details or IP etc so that some one here could verify what you said and see what exactly is the trouble.

Comment: @Michael ssh: connect to host 201.30.001.12 port 1212: Connection timed out
 it seems that ssh is not listening on 1212 as you changed it.

Comment: Use firehol instead of manually creating your rules.  It has a method for you to try a new rule set safely.  If you create a set of rules that disconnect you, then they will revert.

Comment: FYI, SSH can run on multiple ports simultaneously.. It's a good idea to open the second port, try it, if it works disable the original port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your iptables include a line to `ACCEPT` connection states `related` and `established` and you are already connected to the host, you will not be locked out:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -m state --state established,related -J ACCEPT
```

If you want to be extremely cautious, do what I do when testing rules:

```
# iptables-restore < iptables_rules; sleep 30; iptables-restore < clean_rules
```

The idea is apply the rules, wait 30 seconds and apply a set of rules to allow all access. When you execute this line, press `enter` a couple of times and two things can happen:

- Your rules locked you out (pressing `enter` does not show on the screen, so wait the time to run out and they will be cleared;
- If your rules work and you can see the new lines on the screen, `CTRL+C` before the `sleep` ends and you're good.

Comment: I think IPTABLES are not his problem and more over in your rule you did not mentioned any thing about state NEW.He seems to change the port from 22 to some thing else and he is not able to login.I think that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks @coredump; the sleep will do exactly what i'm lookin for

Comment: @regis If I put `new` on that specific rule I would allow ANY new connection, and that's not the point. I add `new` to any rule that has a point, like one allowing access to a port or from a determined address.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the ssh daemon after applying the rules if yes then did it cleanly happened.

What is the output of following command

```
 netstat --inet -pln | grep (your SSH port)
```

Do you see any thing like

```
      Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1089/sshd
```

Replace 22 by your SSH port in above.
Do you see SSH or any other service listening to the ports you changed in netstat's output?
Which config file you changed and what was the change you did?

What is the output of

```
iptables -L -v -n
```

**UPDATE**
Apart from what coredump said it is a practice among sysadmins to have a *cron job* entry which deletes your firewall after 15 minutes when you applied.So this way if you really did some thing wrong after 15 minutes *cron* will flush those rules and you can check again.Like this when you have tested things then you can delete this cron job entry and permanently set the firewall as you wish.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/246685/centos-iptables-fail-on-load-iptables-restore

Comment: @Michael what is the output of netstat ? is there any daemon listening to your changed port your firewall has no meaning.

Comment: netstat came out normal; i was actually able to verify another process through godaddy *via there team; unfort